how to show number of second forward with every double tap?
I am using video js with vue.js. Currently, currently if I double tap 10 times, it will fast forward 100 seconds and show that 100 seconds on the video player at the end when the user stops fast forwarding. I want video js to display 10 seconds 10 times when the user fast forwarding, just like YouTube.
here is the code, time update this function is called
   this.player.off('timeupdate', this.handlePlayerProgress)

full function
    handlePlayerProgress() {
      const currentTime = this.player.currentTime()
      this.timeLog = currentTime
      if (!this.$page.props.isAuth) return null

      const duration = this.player.duration()

      if (!duration || duration <= 0) {
        return false
      }

      if (this.nextEpisodeData && this.$page.props.auth.next_episode_redirect && duration && duration > 0) {
        this.showNextEpisode = duration - currentTime <= 120
      }

      if (
        duration - currentTime <= 120 &&
        this.userVotedPost === false &&
        !this.likeDialogForceClosed &&
        (!this.nextEpisodeData ||
          parseInt(this.nextEpisodeData.season_index) !== parseInt(this.$route.params.seasonIndex))
      ) {
        //this.commentDialog = true;
        this.likeDialog = true
      }

      if (duration > 0 && this.lastPosition < currentTime && currentTime - this.lastPosition > 15) {
        this.lastPosition = currentTime
        axios
          .post('/api/user/watchedTime', {
            post_slug: this.post.slug,
            season_index: this.seasonIndex,
            episode_index: this.episodeIndex,
            watched_time: this.lastPosition,
            max_duration: duration,
            user_has_voted: this.post.userVotedPost !== null,
          })
          .then((response) => {
            if (!response.data.status) {
              //this.showError('Si è verificato un errore durante il salvataggio del tempo visualizzato (codice: Err 1)');
            }
          })
          .catch(() => {
            //this.showError('Si è verificato un errore durante il salvataggio del tempo visualizzato (codice: Err 2)');
          })
      }
    },

html code
  <div ref="videoContainer" :class="{ videoContainer: true, videoContainerSafari: safariIos }">
            <video id="video-player" ref="videoPlayer" autoplay class="vjs-theme-fantasy video-js" />
</div>


i tried using seeking and seeked events but nothing happening
here is video player options
  data: () => {
    return {
      mouseMoveTimer: null,
      showSeasonEpisodesList: false,
      fastLogin: false,
      player: null,
      loading: false,
      disabledForFreeDialog: false,
      likeDialog: false,
      loadingVote: false,
      timeOutDialog: false,
      likeDialogForceClosed: false,
      showNextEpisode: false,
      playerStatus: {
        userActive: true,
        played: true,
      },
      lastPosition: 0,
      debugHeaders: null,
      playerOptions: {
        techOrder: ['chromecast', 'html5'],
        language: 'it',
        playbackRates: [0.5, 1.0, 1.5, 2.0],
        normalizeAutoplay: true,
        controls: true,
        autoplay: true,
        fullscreenElement: document.querySelector('.videoWrap'),
        plugins: {
          mobileUi: {
            fullscreen: {
              iOS: false,
            },
          },
          seekButtons: {
            forward: 10,
            back: 10,
          },
        },
        controlBar: {
          children: {
            PlayToggle: true,
            VolumePanel: true,
            CurrentTimeDisplay: true,
            ProgressControl: true,
            RemainingTimeDisplay: true,
            /*
            DurationDisplay: true,*/
            SubtitlesButton: true,
            CaptionsButton: true,
            PictureInPictureToggle: true,
            qualitySelector: true,
            AirPlayButton: true,
            ChromecastButton: true,
            FullscreenToggle: true,
          },
        },
      },
      trackSettingsModel: {
        fontPercent: '1.00',
        color: '#FFF',
        backgroundColor: '#000',
        backgroundOpacity: '1',
        textOpacity: '1',
      },
      trackSettingsOptions: {
        fontPercent: [
          {
            text: '50%',
            value: 0.5,
          },
          {
            text: '75%',
            value: 0.75,
          },
          {
            text: '100%',
            value: '1.00',
          },
          {
            text: '125%',
            value: 1.25,
          },
          {
            text: '150%',
            value: 1.5,
          },
          {
            text: '175%',
            value: 1.75,
          },
          {
            text: '200%',
            value: 2,
          },
          {
            text: '300%',
            value: 3,
          },
        ],
        colors: [
          {
            value: '#FFF',
            text: 'Bianco',
          },
          {
            value: '#000',
            text: 'Nero',
          },
          {
            value: '#F00',
            text: 'Rosso',
          },
          {
            value: '#0F0',
            text: 'Verde',
          },
          {
            value: '#00F',
            text: 'Blu',
          },
          {
            value: '#FF0',
            text: 'Giallo',
          },
          {
            value: '#F0F',
            text: 'Magenta',
          },
          {
            value: '#0FF',
            text: 'Ciano',
          },
        ],
        opacities: [
          {
            text: 'Opaco',
            value: '1',
          },
          {
            text: 'Semi-Trasparente',
            value: '0.5',
          },
          {
            text: 'Trasparente',
            value: '0',
          },
        ],
        textOpacities: [
          {
            text: 'Opaco',
            value: '1',
          },
          {
            text: 'Semi-Trasparente',
            value: '0.5',
          },
        ],
      },
    }
  },

